# How to start an Activity at the start up or boot of phone in android

Tags: android

I want hint of how can I perform a task at start up or boot of phone in android so I can perform a task that the user can't see.

I don't know `BroadcastReceiver` so kindly show me a way how can I do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this [tutorial](http://www.anddev.org/launch_activity_on_system-emulator_startup-t428.html). I think it should answer the question.

Comment: Ok I see your point- many similar questions asked. I don't know the policy in this case. Should I delete my answer and flag the post as duplicate?

Comment: see i tried my best dear but not getting proper output thats why this question is posted twice by me there is nothing reason